# Team project collections won't start after upgrading to TFS 2017 update 3

Tags: tfs

I installed TFS 2017 Update 3 on our server, using the server configuration wizard. The wizard stated that the upgrade succeeded, although it issued the following warning:

> TF400109: An error occurred while queuing a Team Project Collection servicing job.  Please see the log file for additional information.

Here's what was in the log file:

```
[Info   @20:25:00.970] +-+-+-+-+-| Running UpgradeExistingCollections: 
Queuing Team Project Collection Servicing |+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @20:25:00.971] 
[Info   @20:25:00.971] +-+-+-+-+-| Queuing Team Project Collection Servicing 
|+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @20:25:00.971] Starting Node: CQUEUESERVICING
[Info   @20:25:00.971] NodePath : 
Container/Conditional/Progress/CQUEUESERVICING
[Info   @20:25:01.001] Queuing Team Project Collection Servicing
[Error  @20:25:01.007] Error queuing poject collection upgrade
[Error  @20:25:01.019] 
Exception Message: Status Reason='Upgrading the Team Foundation Service 
Instance.' HostId='bfd035e2-4df0-4709-9aa2-fbf0c6aa14e4' Name='TEAM 
FOUNDATION' (type HostShutdownException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.HostProperties.ThrowShutdownException(Boolean isExternalRequest)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.VssServiceHost.CheckShutdown()
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.DeploymentServiceHost.CreateContext(HostRequestType type, Boolean throwIfShutdown)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ConfigureQueueCollectionServicing.Run(ActivityContext context)

[Info   @20:25:01.020] Node returned: Warning
[Warning@20:25:01.022] TF400109: An error occurred while queuing a Team 
Project Collection servicing job.  Please see the log file for additional 
information.
[Info   @20:25:01.031] Completed UpgradeExistingCollections: Warning
[Info   @20:25:01.031] -----------------------------------------------------
```

From what I can tell (and despite how stupid that sounds), it looks like the upgrade process is unable to upgrade the collection databases because it detects that the process itself is running.

I'm a total noob to TFS. What am I missing here? How can I make my project collections online again?

Comment: What version are you upgrading from?

Answer (score 0):

Seems related to the `Tfs_Configuration` database. Do you have a backup for the `Tfs_Configuration` database. If it is , then you can try to restore it --> Unconfigure TFS --> Run the upgrade wizard again.

You can reference the solution in this similar thread: [TFS 2015 Update 1 - TF400109: An error occurred while queuing a Team Project Collection servicing job.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8da217af-d115-4442-9845-89b6a67c18a6/tfs-2015-update-1-tf400109-an-error-occurred-while-queuing-a-team-project-collection-servicing?forum=tfsadmin)

> 1. Restore Tfs_Configuration database (prior to upgrade)
> 2. Unconfigure TFS. You can do this by running "`C:\Program
>      Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Tools\Tfsconfig setup
>      /uninstall:all`" from the elevate command prompt. (`TFS 2017: %programfiles%\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 15.0\Tools` see [Manage TFS server configuration with TFSConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/tfs-server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd#accounts) for details.)
> 3. Restart Team Foundation Server Administration Console to and try
>      configure TFS using upgrade wizard again i.e. using tfs_server.exe
>      and then upgrade option.
> 4. Take Full backup with Configure backup option in Team Foundation
>      console, as recovery model changed to simple during upgrade